# Sub-heading is displayed inline

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.head {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
  height: 40px;
}
h3 {
  display: inline;
  padding: 8px 0px 0px 10px;
  width: 45%;
}
#underFruits {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.btn {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <h3>Fruits</h3>
  <span id="underFruits">Put me Under Fruits</span>

  <div class="right" style="display: inline-block;">
    <div id="Btn1" class="btn" style="display: inline-block;">Btn1</div>
    <div id="Btn2" class="btn" style="display: inline-block;">Btn2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is,

[image: Expected result]

I want to move text "Put me Under Fruits" actually under H3 heading,

Please note, I can't make any change to class "head" or .btn

Comment: You made `h3` inline that's why it's happening. `h3` is supposed to be a block level element. You should either make your `h3` or `span` block.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia that didn't helped, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="head">
    <div style="float:left">
        <h3>Fruits</h3>
        <div id="underFruits" style="margin-left:10px">Put me Under Fruits</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div id="Btn1" class="btn" style="display: inline-block;">Btn1</div>
        <div id="Btn2" class="btn" style="display: inline-block;">Btn2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like below.

```
<div class="head">
 <div style="display:inline-block;">
  <h3>Fruits</h3>
  <div id="underFruits">Put me Under Fruits</div>
 </div>
 <div class="right" style="display: inline-block;">
    <div id="Btn1" class="btn" style="display: inline-block;">Btn1</div>
    <div id="Btn2" class="btn" style="display: inline-block;">Btn2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/19n9ou66/4/)